# Unity 3D how to get/post a list from REST API

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, post, get

Im having a problem with get/post a list from/to REST server with Unity 3D and C#.

My server:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)
url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/"
list = ["1","2","3","4"]


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello"
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify(list)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = 5000,debug=True)
```

How do i Download the list of objects in Unity and save it to a variable? Also how do i post/update another list? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-CreatingDownloadHandlers.html

with this tutorial i got the "Hello" text returnet but it only returns "1" when using

```
byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
Debug.Log(results)
```

edit: my Python client:

```
import json 
import requests

list = " "
api_url = 'http://ipaddress:5000/list/'
r = requests.get(url = api_url, json=list)
a = r.content

if "3" in a:
    print "found"
```

When client is ran, it prints "found" so it returns the wole list. in Unity i get: [1,]

Comment: Get the text version: `www.downloadHandler.text` instead of `www.downloadHandler.data`

Comment: Works the same way, i only get the first value on the list

Comment: Then that's what the sever is sending. On your server, try to log the data you're sending.

Comment: The server sends the whole list, atleast it does to my python client.

Comment: Edit your question and post what the python client is getting. Now, add what Unity is getting. Finally, if you don't mind share the url you're making the request to

Comment: Question edited. And to be clear, yes "Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);" returns the list but as string. How do i assing it to variable that is list.

Comment: I asked you to post the data the client is receiving not the python code. I suspect this to be json. If so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705) post

Comment: If i print the r.content i get ["1","2", etc.] but each number on its on line

Comment: If you print `www.downloadHandler.text` what's the data?

Comment: Its the same ["1","2", etc.] but each number on its on line. But how do i assign this to a list in unity?

Answer (score 1):

You said that the received data is this format:  `["1","2", etc.]` and you want the data separated by comma in a List.

First, this is just a text data. Retrieve the text data from `www.downloadHandler.text` instead of `www.downloadHandler.data`. Remove the `[` and `]` then split the final string by comma  into array or list.

```
string results = www.downloadHandler.text;
string trimmed = results.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
List<string> splitResult = trimmed.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

Note that you need to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code in order to use the `ToList` function above.

Comment: The last object on the list seems to have the ] bracket still on when i print the splitresult list.